# How to bind datagridcells in a template to nested objects

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

The real plug-in for a MVVM application is based on a csv file in a shared DropBox. One of the columns (in below simplified example "B") might have cell values that need explanation with images. Therefore we add a folder in the DropBox if needed, named with the cell value ("B1" in the example), containing images. Eventually these images should become thumbnails, and full screen images if a thumbnail is selected. But for now it would be great if the added column could display the file paths belonging to a cell value in column "B" in an adjacent cell. However after days of research and trial and error the result is:
[Cell in front of A0 and A1 both show D:\Temp\B1\test0.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cfbmz.png) 
While the cell in front of A0 should be empty and in front of A1 should read:
D:\Temp\B1\test0.jpg
D:\Temp\B1\test1.jpg

I have next questions:

1. Why do I have to set the DataContext again for the ListBox and for
   the TextBlock? It was already set for the Window. Are they not in
   the logical tree?
2. Why is only the first file displayed and why in
       all cells of the column?
3. What am I doing wrong?

The View:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication3.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:myViewModel="clr-namespace:WpfApplication3" 
        Title="MainWindow" Height="120" Width="200">
    <Window.Resources>
        <myViewModel:testConverter x:Key="myTestConverter"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Window.DataContext>
        <myViewModel:ViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid x:Name="myXAMLtable" AutoGenerateColumns="True" CanUserAddRows="False"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding PropDataTable}">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ListBox x:Name="folder" ItemsSource="{Binding MyImageFolderList,
                                     Converter={StaticResource myTestConverter}}">
                                <ListBox.DataContext>
                                    <myViewModel:ViewModel/>
                                </ListBox.DataContext>
                                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyImageFolderList/MyImageList/MyImagePath}">
                                            <TextBlock.DataContext>
                                                <myViewModel:ViewModel/>
                                            </TextBlock.DataContext>
                                        </TextBlock>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            </ListBox>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

(I used a dummy converter to test the binding, a trick I learned in stackoverflow)
The ViewModel:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;

namespace WpfApplication3
{
    class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
            }
        }
        //private Model _Model; //for clarity left out
        private DataTable propDataTable;
        public DataTable PropDataTable
        {
            get { return propDataTable; }
            set
            {
                propDataTable = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("PropDataTable");
            }
        }
        private List<MyImageFolder> myImageFolderList;
        public List<MyImageFolder> MyImageFolderList
        {
            get { return myImageFolderList; }
            set
            {
                myImageFolderList = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("MyImageFolderList");
            }
        }
        public ViewModel()
        {
            DataTable tempPropDataTable = new DataTable();
            tempPropDataTable.Columns.Add("A", typeof(string));
            tempPropDataTable.Columns.Add("B", typeof(string));
            DataRow row0 = tempPropDataTable.NewRow();
            DataRow row1 = tempPropDataTable.NewRow();
            row0[0] = "A0";
            row0[1] = "B0";
            row1[0] = "A1";
            row1[1] = "B1";
            tempPropDataTable.Rows.Add(row0);
            tempPropDataTable.Rows.Add(row1);
            PropDataTable = tempPropDataTable;

            MyImageFolderList = new List<MyImageFolder>();
            //in D:\Temp\B1 there are two filesP test0.jpg and test1.jpg
            string B0 = "D:\\Temp\\B1\\test0.jpg";
            string B1 = "D:\\Temp\\B1\\test1.jpg";
            MyImageFolder mif = new MyImageFolder("B1");
            MyImage mi0 = new MyImage(B0);
            MyImage mi1 = new MyImage(B1);
            mif.MyImageList = new List<MyImage>();//did you forget this???
            mif.MyImageList.Add(mi0);
            mif.MyImageList.Add(mi1);
            MyImageFolderList.Add(mif);
        }
    }
}
```

The MyImageFolder class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace WpfApplication3
{
    public class MyImageFolder : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
            }
        }
        private string myImageFolderPath = "";
        public string MyImageFolderPath
        {
            get { return myImageFolderPath; }
            set
            {
                myImageFolderPath = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("MyImageFolderPath");
            }
        }
        private List<MyImage> myImageList = new List<MyImage>();
        public List<MyImage> MyImageList
        {
            get { return myImageList; }
            set
            {
                myImageList = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("MyImageList");
            }
        }
        public MyImageFolder(string fp)
        {
            this.MyImageFolderPath = fp;
        }
    }
}
```

The MyImage class:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace WpfApplication3
{
    public class MyImage : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
            }
        }
        private string myImagePath = "";
        public string MyImagePath
        {
            get { return myImagePath; }
            set
            {
                myImagePath = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("MyImagePath");
            }
        }
        //constructor
        public MyImage(string ip)
        {
            MyImagePath = ip;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Everywhere you are writing something like

```
<ListBox.DataContext>
    <myViewModel:ViewModel/>
</ListBox.DataContext>
```

You are creating a new instance of the ViewModel class and setting it to the DataContext behind the UI object. This is almost never what you want, because the end result is something like this (note the many instances of the ViewModel object) :

```
<DataGridRow DataContext=ViewModel1.PropDataTable[0]>
    <ListBoxItem DataContext=ViewModel2.MyImageFolderList[0]>
        <TextBlock DataContext=ViewModel3.MyImageFolderPath />
    </ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem DataContext=ViewModel2.MyImageFolderList[1]>
        <TextBlock DataContext=ViewModel4.MyImageFolderPath />
    </ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem DataContext=ViewModel2.MyImageFolderList[2]>
        <TextBlock DataContext=ViewModel5.MyImageFolderPath />
    </ListBoxItem>
</DataGridItem>

<DataGridRow DataContext=ViewModel1.PropDataTable[1]>
    <ListBoxItem DataContext=ViewModel6.MyImageFolderList[0]>
        <TextBlock DataContext=ViewModel7.MyImageFolderPath />
    </ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem DataContext=ViewModel6.MyImageFolderList[1]>
        <TextBlock DataContext=ViewModel8.MyImageFolderPath />
    </ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem DataContext=ViewModel6.MyImageFolderList[2]>
        <TextBlock DataContext=ViewModel.MyImageFolderPath />
    </ListBoxItem>
</DataGridRow>
```

The DataContext is inherited from the parent control, so you should write you bindings with that assumption.

What you want is ONE copy of your ViewModel object, which as a property called PropDataTable that is a collection of objects. Each object in PropDataTable should have a collection of objects called MyImageFolderList, and each item in MyImageFolderList should have a property called MyImageFolderPath.

So if you have the following (note the lack of assigning .DataContext to a new instance of ViewModel)

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding PropDataTable"}>
    ...
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyImageFolderList"}>
        ...
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyImageFolderPath}" />
        ...
    </ListBox>
</DataGrid>
```

It actually renders as something along these lines :

```
<DataGridRow DataContext=ViewModel1.PropDataTable[0]>
    <ListBoxItem DataContext=ViewModel1.PropDataTable[0].MyImageFolderList[0]>
        <TextBlock DataContext=ViewModel1.PropDataTable[0].MyImageFolderList[0].MyImageFolderPath />
    </ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem DataContext=ViewModel1.PropDataTable[0].MyImageFolderList[1]>
        <TextBlock DataContext=ViewModel1.PropDataTable[0].MyImageFolderList[1].MyImageFolderPath />
    </ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem DataContext=ViewModel1.PropDataTable[0].MyImageFolderList[2]>
        <TextBlock DataContext=ViewModel1.PropDataTable[0].MyImageFolderList[2].MyImageFolderPath />
    </ListBoxItem>
</DataGridItem>

<DataGridRow DataContext=ViewModel1.PropDataTable[1]>
    <ListBoxItem DataContext=ViewModel1.PropDataTable[1].MyImageFolderList[0]>
        <TextBlock DataContext=ViewModel1.PropDataTable[1].MyImageFolderList[0].MyImageFolderPath />
    </ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem DataContext=ViewModel1.PropDataTable[1].MyImageFolderList[1]>
        <TextBlock DataContext=ViewModel1.PropDataTable[1].MyImageFolderList[1].MyImageFolderPath />
    </ListBoxItem>
</DataGridRow>
```

I have an article on my blog that goes into the DataContext in a bit more detail if you're struggling to understand it as well. [What is this "DataContext" you speak of?](https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2012/07/14/what-is-this-datacontext-you-speak-of/)

Comment: So TextBox should be bound to string property: string **ImagePath** of object _Image_. The parent of TextBox (ListBox) is bound to property: List<Image> **ImageList**. The parent of ListBox (DataGrid) is bound to the property: DataTable **PropDataTable** which contains the objects that has the ImageList property. I call these objects _Item_.  So _Item_ has a property List<Image> **ImageList** and _Image_ has a property string **ImagePath**. If the reasoning is right, what can be wrong with my code? I have put it on GitHub [link]( https://github.com/jhubers/test).

Comment: @H.H. `PropDataTable` is a DataTable object, and DataTable does not have a property called `ImageList`. Change PropDataTable to a collection of objects which contain a public List<Image> property called `ImageList`

Comment: I don't get this. If PropDataTable is not a DataTable, how can I use it to make a DataGrid? Or is every row of the DataGrid filled with the objects in the collection until the row is full and then the next row? Also in the real plug-in I don't know how many columns there are in the changing csv file...

Comment: Usually I would recommend making the property a `List<T>` of MyClass objects, where MyClass contains public properties of the fields you want, however since the columns aren't known at runtime and could change, a DataTable might be a bit better. Try manually adding an extra column to your DataTable with the fieldname of ImageList... if you can't set the datatype of the column to a List<Image> then you might need to leave it as an object and use an IValueConverter to convert it from object to List<Image> in the binding

Comment: I can add a column to the DataTable of type List<Image>, but the datagrid then shows (Collection) in the cell. How do I get to the content of the collection?

Comment: You'll have to use a DataGridTemplateColumn like you have in your original question, and I would probably use an IValueConverter to convert the DataRow (which will be the DataContext of your Template) to your List<Image>... it sounds like your grid will have variable columns, but the List<Image> will always be static. Btw if your grid does NOT have variable columns, I would highly recommend making a custom class for it instead of using the DataTable

Comment: var item = (DataRowView)value;
return item[0]; this works. Thanks.